# Sqlite 3.7 on amazon ec2 with Engine Yard

Tags: sqlite, amazon-ec2, engineyard

How can i update the version of sqlite3 on my amazon ec2 instance deployed with engine yard ?
Currently the version is 3.6.13, but i need 3.7.x version to use WAL feature of sqlite.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading is possible by writing a custom Chef recipie.
Note that Engine Yard won't support your software setup if you do upgrade.

Source:
https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21009947-Upgrade-to-a-more-modern-version-of-ImageMagick

Howto for creating a custom recipie: https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21009867-Customize-Your-Environment-with-Chef-Recipes